# layouts\default.vue will be reset after I restart the nuxt.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, layout, nuxt.js

I'm currently trying to learn vue.js on the nuxtjs server in the localhost:3000.

I have found out a problem that whenever I create a new **"xxxx.vue"** file in the **"pages"** directory or restarting the nuxt.js server, the server will generate a new **"default.vue"** file to replace my old one **(in \layouts\default.vue)**.

How can this problem to be solved? Is there any way to prevent it from generating a new file to replace it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi trevorchiu, which command do you use to restart the nuxt server?

Comment: actually i can't find a method to close the server, so i just terminate it and use coomand "npm run dev" to start it

Comment: Do you have a [repro] here? Something is probably wrong but not what you think. The default layout does not get replaced at any point of time.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem in Windows. The file is overwritten anytime Visual Studio Code recognizes a change to code and rebuilds. 

Nuxt @ v2.15.8    Fresh nuxt install - brand new project

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you modified the **.nuxt\layouts\default.vue**, it will reset after the dev server restart. If you want modify the layout, ignore this file, and create (or copy) a **layouts\default.vue** in your root directory, and modify this file.

Comment: Generally, do not touch files in `.nuxt` or `dist`.